# Use Clang to extract c++ function definitions and declarations

Tags: c++, clang, doxygen

I want to use a tool like Clang or Cppest to extract/parse the functions declarations and definitions from some cpp files. The problem is that the documentations are too poor. I can't find anything useful and simple.

So is there any other tools that can help me with this? Or is there any good documentations or examples regarding using Clang or Cppest?

Also, I was checking Doxygen and found that maybe It can help either, but couldn't find any examples.

Comment: StackOverflow is a platform to ask questions about specific problems. And asking for off-site resources is off-topic.

Comment: Is Cppest the right name? Please give a reference to it. Regarding doxygen just set the relevant configuration options, try it and see what the results are.

Comment: For clang you are probably looking for [How to write RecursiveASTVisitor based ASTFrontendActions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html). In general you want to parse the source-code to AST and traverse it to search for the declarations and definitions.